# ASP.Net 4.6 Task await not returning

Tags: c#, async-await, task

I'm making a basic POST to receive an auth Token from an API.
My code starts the Task from a button press.

```
Task<DataClass.AuthenticationToken> token = GetAuthTokenAsync(tbUsername.Text.Trim(), tbPassword.Text.Trim());
```

The task should return my token information in a data structure defined in "dataclass"

```
private async Task<DataClass.AuthenticationToken> GetAuthTokenAsync(string username, string password)
{
    string requestURL = DataClass.CloudAPIBaseURL + DataClass.CloudTokenURL;
    HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
    HttpResponseMessage response = new HttpResponseMessage();
    DataClass.AuthenticationRequest request = new DataClass.AuthenticationRequest
    {
        username = username,
        password = password
    };

    DataClass.AuthenticationToken token = new DataClass.AuthenticationToken();

    // Post request
    response = await client.PostAsJsonAsync(requestURL, request);

    //never gets here!!!
    // I will complete coding once I get the response.

    //string statusCode = response.StatusCode.ToString();
    return token;
}
```

Using Fiddler, I see my POST going out and the response containing the correct authorizing data.
For some reason, the async await is not returning.

Comment: Do you have visibility into what ever `client.PostAsJsonAsync(requestURL, request)` is hitting? You'll need to debug that if its yours to see why it's never returning. Your await is just doing it's job and waiting for it to finish.

Comment: Did you try to set the `Timeout` of the HttpClient to 1 or 2 seconds (the [default](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.http.httpclient.timeout?view=net-5.0#remarks) is 100!)?  Does it behave in the same way?

Comment: After you call `GetAuthTokenAsync`, how are you accessing the result of `token`? This seems like a probable deadlock to me.

Answer (score 1):

The issue could be that the call to `GetAuthTokenAsync` isn't being awaited:

```
Task<DataClass.AuthenticationToken> token = GetAuthTokenAsync(tbUsername.Text.Trim(), tbPassword.Text.Trim());
```

Try this:

```
DataClass.AuthenticationToken token = await GetAuthTokenAsync(tbUsername.Text.Trim(), tbPassword.Text.Trim());
```

Comment: Adding `await` there won't work, since it's assigning to a `Task<T>`, and not grabbing the result.

Comment: Nice catch. Fixed it.

Answer (score 0):

You can try first to check whether  `client.PostAsJsonAsync(requestURL, request)` will return a value called synchronously i.e without awaiting the call:

```
response = client.PostAsJsonAsync(requestURL, request).Result;
```

If it returns a value maybe the problem is in the surrounding code that calls `GetAuthTokenAsync` i.e. it does not wait for the Task to complete or similar issue.

Comment: calling client.PostAsJsonAsync without 'await' returns immediately with response Status = "waiting for activation".  I can't add .Result; when using 'await" to this as there is a warning.  I testing using no wait and with .Result, which does wait for something.  What I got back was "unauthorized" although Fiddler returns the correct authocodes.  So...what to try next?

Comment: Well if you got "unauthorized", this means that you have received some response after all. Research why you got "unauthorized" : invalid token, wrong password, things like that.

Answer (score 0):

Trying the last suggestion:

```
DataClass.AuthenticationToken token = await GetAuthTokenAsync(tbUsername.Text.Trim(), tbPassword.Text.Trim());
```

the compiler does not allow this as a call to an async Task.  The format I used to invoke the Task is correct.  Continued experimenting for 5 days, I landed on NOT using the TASK await method.  Instead I changed the Task to a function GetAuthToken(parameters).
Using the PostAsJsonAsync without await and adding .Result, the method awaits for a result.

```
HttpResponseMessage response = client.PostAsJsonAsync(requestURL, request).Result;
if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
{
    // Ok 
    string data = response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;                
    thisToken = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<DataClass.AuthenticationToken>(data);
}
```

I used Newtonsoft to deserialize the data and voila.  I can continue with my project!

Note to all those who tried to help.  Thank you.  It would be helpful however, if you first test your suggestions as some were just not valid coding syntax.